# capturar un mapa de google maps y mostrarlo en pdf android

Tags: android, google-maps

Tengo una app donde necesito mostrar el mapa de google de una ubicacion en mi reporte de pdf.

[image: Ejemplo de Reporteria]

Comment: Añade mas codigo, muestranos **tu esfuerzo, lo que hace hecho** este no es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas donde esperes resultados sin haber hecho nada.

Comment: Me parece un poco amplia tu pregunta: Añade detalles para reducir el conjunto de respuestas o separar un problema que se puede responder en pocos párrafos.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar los Static Maps API de Google en la cual llamas una URL y te retorna una imagen con los requerimientos que le envias.

```
double latitud =40.416786;
double longitud= -3.703680;
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitud + "," + longitud+ "&zoom=15&size=400x400&sensor=false
```

El resultado seria este: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.416786,-3.703680&zoom=15&size=400x400&sensor=false

Si necesitas colocar marcadores y otras personalizaciones, puedes ver la documentación [aquí](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/?csw=1)

Comment: Gracias, esta genial . Saludos.